# GetX: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'S' doesn't allow null

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

Started getting this error:
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/get-4.6.5/lib/
get_instance/src/get_instance.dart:281:5:
Error: A non-null value must be returned since
the return type 'S' doesn't allow null.

the referred code is the find fuction in get_instance.dart file:

```dart
/// Finds the registered type <[S]> (or [tag])
  /// In case of using Get.[create] to register a type <[S]> or [tag],
  /// it will create an instance each time you call [find].
  /// If the registered type <[S]> (or [tag]) is a Controller,
  /// it will initialize it's lifecycle.
  S find<S>({String? tag}) {
    final key = _getKey(S, tag);
    if (isRegistered<S>(tag: tag)) {
      final dep = _singl[key];
      if (dep == null) {
        if (tag == null) {
          throw 'Class "$S" is not registered';
        } else {
          throw 'Class "$S" with tag "$tag" is not registered';
        }
      }

      // if (dep.lateRemove != null) {
      //   dep.isDirty = true;
      //   if(dep.fenix)
      // }

      /// although dirty solution, the lifecycle starts inside
      /// `initDependencies`, so we have to return the instance from there
      /// to make it compatible with `Get.create()`.
      final i = _initDependencies<S>(name: tag);
      return i ?? dep.getDependency() as S;
    } else {
      // ignore: lines_longer_than_80_chthrow '"$S" not found. You need to call "Get.put($S())" or "Get.lazyPut(()=>$S())"';
    }
  }
```

**Reproduction code
Create a new project:
Simply import the package:

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
```

Flutter version is:

```
Flutter 3.10.4 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 682aa387cf (7 days ago) • 2023-06-05 18:04:56 -0500
Engine • revision 2a3401c9bb
Tools • Dart 3.0.3 • DevTools 2.23.1
```

I've recently updated from 3.10.3, but even downgrading the error persists.
I've also tried to downgrade to 3.10.0 (which supposedly worked) without results.

The error is the same on any platform.

any hint on how to investigate?

Comment: thank you. It has a lot of limitations and problems indeed. Even if actually in this case the problem didnt involve getx

Answer (score 0):

to anybody who incurs in this, I solved the issue installing a new instance of flutter and (suggested while running flutter doctor) doing a `dart pub cache clean`.

Don't really know whether running `dart pub cache clean` would have been enough.

The suspect that the problem was related to the framework instance came from the fact that downgrading to the flutter previous (and working) version didn't affect the errors in the build process.